# Kendo UI master detail grid with custom button?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

The following is the kendo master detail grid i am working in angular js. Kendo by default giving action to dropdown arrow on left side. But i need to open detail grid by clicking "+" button at the end of row. Please anybody help me?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4tj3aonju92c65/Screenshot%202015-08-17%2012.18.21.png?dl=0